# Finding the position percentage of the object in the a similar sized small rectangle

Tags: radicals, fractions, percentages, rectangles

I am trying to find the position percentage of the object in the lower smaller square.
So the use case is, in the first square(big square) there is an object positioned at 69.335% from the leftmost corner and the rectangle is itself positioned at 27% from left most corner.

I have a smaller rectangle with a different dimension, which is placed at 3.691% from the left-most corner of the main canvas(1368*650). I want to position the object in the same location in the smaller square (that is on the right side of the small square.).

I am unable to formulate it.
Can someone please help?

[image: Rectangle with clear values]

Comment: It is unclear what those percentages mean. Especially the 3.691%, as there are no two lengths visible in the drawing where one is about 27 times longer than the other. ( 0.03691 is about 1/27)

Comment: Let me share another image with clear values

Comment: Hi, @JaapScherphuis can you please recheck this I have updated the picture and rephrased the question a little bit.